# InApp purchase Product ID

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I have n number of items to download from my server through apples InApp Purchase in iPhone. They fall under the price range of 0.99$ to 9.99$. Should i create n different product id's or 9 product id's are enough by making product id's as consumable and use same product id for different  contents. (I have logic in my app to check whether user has already downloaded the content)

Answer (score 1):

**ONE** product id for each of your product. This also covers consumables.

Completely distinctable. If you have a magazine with 12 issues a year, you must make one product id for each of these.

When I pay for a product with a specific product ID, I can demand all content linked to that id.

Comment: Little confusion about your answer.. My doubt is can i use same product id for different products?

Comment: No. Not unless you are selling a bundle of items.

Comment: is there any restriction from apple for doing so? (for selling 2 different products using the only 1 consumable product id)

Comment: Yes. One SKU for every item, both static and consumable. If you want to make it more fluent, you should consider having some inapp economy like tokens or such.